# antenna feeds for SMT GPS patch antenna

Tags: antenna

I am designing a GPS board with an SMT patch antenna (SGP.25cfrom Taoglas). I understand that the rf feed is 50Ohms impedance controlled track. But the datasheet shows 2 feeds - inner feed and outer feed. What are the 2 feeds. Does the inner feed mean that I can place the GPS on one layer and the antenna on the other layer and connect the RF track via the inner feed. In that case how is the impedance controlled through the via.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to leave a hole through the solder mask under the inner feed and provide an isolated pad to solder it to.  Anyway, if you feed from the inner feed, then the outer feed is going to become a stub that could cause some rather major reflection issues.